# can't launch openni on Pandaboard

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ther,

I installed ROS electric (base + perception) from source on an armel platform and try to run a kinect and a webcam on it.

I used this command to install the perception based installation which went smooth and without failures.

```
rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=perception&overlay=no"
```

But when I try to run the included packages:

```
$roslaunch openni_camera camera_node.launch
```

or

```
$roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

or for the Webcam (usb_cam & uvc_camera packages from source):

```
$roslaunch uvc_camera camera_node.launch
```

or

```
$roslaunch usb_cam 'MY OWN LAUNCH FILE
```

I always get the Error: cannot launch node of type [the specific package]: cannot locate node of type [specific node] in package [package]

Is there something wrong with my ROS installation or did I install all four Packages wrong?

the output of the `$echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is

```
/home/panda/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric
```

which is correct

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36316/can%27t-launch-openni-on-pandaboard/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-06-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-12**:
Please provide more information. Which packages did you install, what are the names of the packages that cannot be found. Did you install them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You installed the rosinstall file into ~/ros, but your package path only contains ~/ros_workspace. Given you are using Ubuntu, there is no reason for installing the perception variant from source, i.e. using rosinstall. To install the ros perception variant and the kinect driver, just execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-perception ros-electric-openni-kinect
```

**Edit**: Since you cannot use Ubuntu packages on your platform, you have to install the stack openni_kinect from source. First, you'll have to install the openni driver. I'm not sure where to get it, but I guess the right location is [here](http://www.openni.org/Downloads/OpenSources.aspx). Then you can install the openni_kinect stack. For that, create a new file openni_kinect.rosinstall with the following content:

```
- hg:
    local-name: openni_kinect
    meta:
      repo-name: wg-kforge
    uri: https://kforge.ros.org/openni/openni_ros
```

Then install it with:

```
rosinstall ~/ros_workspace /path/to/openni_kinect.rosinstall
```

Finally, try `rosmake openni_launch`. Please note that you probably won't be able to build the human tracker since it depends on a pre-compiled library for ia64 or i386 that might not work on your pandaboard.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-06-12**:
sorry, that is a typo. I installed the rosinstall file into ~/ros_workspace and not ~/ros. The reason why I installed the perception variant from source is that I'm using a Armel architecture (pandaboard).

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-12**:
Well, then the reason for not being able to find openni_kinect is probably that you just didn't check it out. I'll update my answer.

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-06-12**:
by using `sudo apt-get install ros-electric-perception ros-electric-openni-kinect` I get following output: `Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package ros-electric-perception E: Unable to locate package ros-electric-openni-kinect`

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-06-12**:
now it complains about the platform when I try to install the openni_driver. By using `hg clone "https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers"` then `make` gives me now the failure massege `Unknown platform: armv7l`

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-12**:
Please always copy-paste the exact error message and the commands you were executing. The openni package you try to compile seems to build debian packages and contains nite. That means, it will not work on arm but there is a chance that you get at least openni built. You'll have to change Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like something is wrong with your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable. Did you make sure to add `source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash` to your `.bashrc`?

Could you edit your question with the output of `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`?

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-06-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1